Unexpected non-uniformity of results from some implementations of Jacobson-Matthews seem to show a strange sensitivity to isotopy class
Questions
Why do some Jacobson-Matthews (J-M) implementations for generating random latin squares exhibit frequencies inconsistent with an underlying uniform distribution?
Further investigation suggests that the frequencies are in fact sensitive to the isotopy class in which the  latin squares lie. Is there any theoretical approach which explains this rather surprising result?
The effect has been observed for order 4, 5 and 6 latin squares. Empirical results for higher orders do not seem feasible. This leaves the question: can the effect for higher orders be determined?
The effect seems to be related to the code controlling the iterative calls to the code which makes the J-M 'moves'. Are all implementations which use a similar pattern of iterative calls likely to be subject to this non-uniformity?
A couple of points before outlining the research which have led to this conclusion:

the effect does not seem to depend on whether the 'simpler but lower performing' or the 'more complex higher performance' implementation (as described by Ignacio Gallego Sagastume) is used for executing the moves;

the effect does not seem to depend on the software platform used. Both a Python implementation and a GAP/LOOPS implementation exhibit the effect (both implementations are on a PC under Windows 10). If anyone, surprised by this result, decides to confirm on other platforms, I would be interested to hear about it.


Outline of research.
The non-uniformity was first identified in a GAP/LOOPS implementation of the "simpler" implementation when comparing the results from a completely different algorithm with those from J-M.
To see if it also occurred for the "higher efficiency" case and on a more commonly used language I converted the Go code of Paul Hankin to Python using CodeConvert (www.codeconvert.ai). The  resultant Python programs below demonstrate the results.
Implementation A – gives first indication of non-uniformity
In this Python implementation, 100000 order 4 Latin squares were generated and the occurrences of each of the 576 distinct latin squares tallied. The results showed frequencies occur in two markedly distinct bands - either less than 90 or greater than 170.
Repeated runs of this program indicated the number of squares in the lower band is always 144 which is exactly a quarter of the 576 Latin squares of order 4. The set of 144 Latin squares in the lower band is always the same.
I asked myself the question: what divides the latin squares of order 4 into quarters? Then realised there are 4 reduced latin squares of order 4 and this prompted further investigation which indicated that these 144 squares all reduced to the same Latin square. Of the remaining squares, each reduced to one of the other three reduced squares of order 4.
Further investigation (carried out on the GAP/LOOPS platform which has standard functions for testing isotopy) indicated the 144 squares corresponded to one of the two isotopy classes of order 4 while the remaining squares corresponded to the other.
It therefore appears that the frequency of occurrence of a Latin square of order 4 (under this implementation) is sensitive to the  isotopy class of that square.
This immediately raised the question: what is the situation for higher order Latin squares?
Initial investigations using functions in GAP/LOOPS suggests that the sensitivity exists for order 5 and order 6 Latin squares.  Above order 6 the number of Latin squares is so large does not seem possible to get any meaningful results.
Implementation B – simple change removes  non-uniformity.
Interestingly the above sensitivity is removed by a minor change to the implementation as demonstrated in the second Python program below.  This change simply involves changing the way iterations of the J-A moves are made.
In the implementation A, showing non-uniformity, the number of iterations specified (usually the order cubed) are executed as moves irrespective of whether the result is proper or improper. After these iterations are completed it may be necessary to execute a number of improper moves until a proper square is obtained. This is then returned as the required square.
In B, non-uniformity seems to be removed, and the results appear to support an underlying uniform distribution. This implementation requires each of the specified iterations to conclude with a proper square. So each of the iterations will often require a number of improper moves until a proper square is obtained.
This means the total number of moves actually executed is considerable higher than in A. However it appears this specified number may be reduced without impacting uniformity, e.g. to the square of the order.
What is not clear to me is: why does this change work?  Or from the other point of view, why doesn't an increase in the number of iterations, as in next version, remove the lack of uniformity in  implementation A?
Implementation C specifies a higher number of iterations
This does not remove non-uniformity and I tried other even higher numbers of iterations. Surely if it is raised until the number of iterations is approximately that of implementation B then uniformity would be achieved?  This doesn't seem to be the case.
Implementation D - treats the number of proper squares as the target
This version is similar to A, but counts the number of proper squares encountered in the walk until a specified number is reached. Interestingly this restores uniformity.
Order 5 and 6 latin squares - via reducing the random Latin squares
Given the number of squares which reduce to a given reduced latin square is constant for a given order, higher orders are more efficiently investigated by reducing each random square delivered by J-M and tallying the frequencies of reduced squares. Python code and runs for order 5 are in Implementation E.
Results obtained from extensive runs on GAP/LOOPS where tests for isotopy class are available are:
For order 5 latin squares
There are 56 reduced Latin squares of order 5 and hence 56 sets of Latin squares which reduce to these canonical forms. Running the test with 1,000,000 calls for random Latin squares these 56 sets divided into two classes:
6 contained squares which occurred with frequencies in range (22797,23221);
50 contained squares which occurred with frequencies in range (16918,17557)
Further analysis showed these two classes were the two isotopy classes of order 5.
Order 6
An experiment with 10,000,000 repetitions for order 6 delivered the following results:
 isotopy         number of      frequency       mean
 class id        reduced LS       range
                  in class
    1               120        (750,892)       826.7
    2              1080        (1105,1304)    1203.4
    3                36        (654,827)       742.2
    4                36        (673,774)       734.1
    5                36        (670,797)       730.6
    6              1080        (845,1038)      936.9
    7               540        (998,1221)     1128.1
    8               360        (731,927)       815.9
    9                20        (305,376)       339.5
   10               120        (754,890)       827.6
   11                40        (1182,1343)    1233.5
   12               120        (743,919)       828.9
   13              1080        (1168,1381)    1272.4
   14               540        (599,749)       673.1
   15               360        (726,904)       816.5
   16               360        (734,908)       815.9
   17               540        (1043,1231)    1126.2
   18               540        (1047,1222)    1129.3
   19              1080        (1087,1312)    1203.1
   20              1080        (1093,1315)    1200.3
   21                60        (774,911)       837.3
   22               180        (823,976)       903.9
          Total    9408  
  
(Note: the id has no significance other than as an internal programming identifier for this work)

This indicates significantly different frequencies for Latin squares according to the isotopy class in which they reside. From this one might conclude that non-uniformity is greater for order 6 than for order 5.
It is also worth noting, for example, that the frequency squares in isotopy class id 9 above is less than a third of class id 13. In addition, class 13 contains 54 times more latin squares than class 9. So the combined effect means that a obtaining a representative square of class 13 is more than 150 times that of obtaining a representative of class 9. Interesting situation if hypothetically only class 9 latin squares disprove some conjecture.
Beyond order 6 the large number of latin squares presents a significant processing problem.
So, to determine how significant the non-uniformity is for higher order latin squares may only be possible by understanding the root cause of the non-uniformity.
The possibility of non-uniformity can, of course, be avoided by ensuring an implementation of the type illustrated in Implementation B.
Python implementations
#IMPLEMENTATION A
# This is a Python implementation of the Jacobson Matthews algorithm derived
# from a conversion of the Go code of Paul Hankin.
# It is an implementation of the so called 'efficient' version of Jacobson-Matthews. 
# Conversion from Go to Python was by via CodeConvert (www.codeconvert.ai)
# with a minor necessary modification as annotated in the code. 
# This version exhibits an interesting pattern of non-uniformity.

import random
import time
import numpy as np

def rand2(a, b):
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return a, b
    return b, a

def Latin(n):
    xy = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    xz = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    yz = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            k = (i + j) % n
            xy[i][j] = k
            xz[i][k] = j
            yz[j][k] = i

    mxy, mxz, myz = 0, 0, 0
    m = [0, 0, 0]
    proper = True
    min_iter = n*n*n                    
    iter = 0                              # Code replacing a conditional Go 'for' statement   
    while (iter<min_iter or not proper):  # which did not translate correctly
        iter = iter + 1                   #
        if proper:
            i, j, k = random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1)
            while xy[i][j] == k:
                i, j, k = random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1)
            i2 = yz[j][k]
            j2 = xz[i][k]
            k2 = xy[i][j]
            i2_, j2_, k2_ = i, j, k
        else:
            i, j, k = m
            i2, i2_ = rand2(yz[j][k], myz)
            j2, j2_ = rand2(xz[i][k], mxz)
            k2, k2_ = rand2(xy[i][j], mxy)

        proper = xy[i2][j2] == k2
        if not proper:
            m = [i2, j2, k2]
            mxy = xy[i2][j2]
            myz = yz[j2][k2]
            mxz = xz[i2][k2]

        xy[i][j] = k2_
        xy[i][j2] = k2
        xy[i2][j] = k2
        xy[i2][j2] = k

        yz[j][k] = i2_
        yz[j][k2] = i2
        yz[j2][k] = i2
        yz[j2][k2] = i

        xz[i][k] = j2_
        xz[i][k2] = j2
        xz[i2][k] = j2
        xz[i2][k2] = j

    return xy   # END OF TRANSLATED CODE

# CODE RUNNING THE ABOVE TO DEMONSTRATE NON UNIFORMITY FOR ORDER 4 LATIN SQUARES
# this code uses the above to generate R latin squares of order N and store a copy of 
# each distinct square in a list. (list very long if n > 4) 
# It tallies the number of occurences of each in a corresponding list.
# This aims to demonstrate that occurences occur in two distinct bands.
# for 100000 squares the count list indicates that frequencies of the latin
# squares are either less than 90 or greater than 170.
# 100 lies between these two bands and is used as a 'cut' to
# enable squares in the lower band to be placed in list lowtabs.
# Interestingly the number in the lower band is always 144, exactly a quarter of the 576
# latin squares of order 4. It is easily demonstrated that the same set of latin squares  
# constitutes the lower band for any execution of the program.

random.seed(time.time_ns())
N = 4        # order of latin squares
R = 100000   # number of repetitions 
tabs = []     # holds a copy of each distinct latin square
counts = []   # holds the corresponding frequency
cut =100
ix = 0

for nm in range(R):
    t = Latin(N)
    try:
        ix = tabs.index(t)  # test if already in list
    except ValueError:
        tabs.append(t)      # if not add to list
        counts.append(0)    # set count to zero
        
    ix = tabs.index(t)     
    counts[ix] = counts[ix] + 1  # increaase count
    

print( "list of frequency counts \n",counts)
print ("mean = ",round(np.mean(counts),3))
print( "standard deviation = ",round(np.std(counts),3))
print("number of latin squares = ",len(tabs))

lowcounts = []     # list of counts less than cut
lowtabs = []       # list of corresponding squares.
for k in range(len(counts)):
    if counts[k] < cut:
        lowtabs.append(tabs[k])
        lowcounts.append(counts[k])


print("number of low freq squares = ",len(lowtabs))


A run of the above:
list of frequency counts
[243, 217, 217, 214, 213, 209, 207, 187, 189, 224, 59, 65, 207, 225, 208, 224, 225, 234, 230, 198, 217, 229, 202, 237, 204, 51, 236, 207, 225, 228, 221, 208, 217, 206, 224, 203, 220, 230, 199, 213, 231, 222, 203, 210, 45, 211, 223, 206, 66, 197, 237, 226, 223, 207, 213, 207, 212, 230, 47, 203, 206, 219, 65, 199, 206, 192, 196, 189, 222, 237, 55, 209, 227, 219, 211, 214, 221, 217, 235, 205, 51, 205, 53, 221, 204, 218, 190, 56, 209, 200, 221, 204, 209, 44, 189, 230, 229, 227, 195, 200, 183, 243, 55, 61, 213, 207, 201, 217, 215, 226, 62, 221, 238, 227, 57, 225, 236, 197, 213, 185, 209, 199, 215, 217, 213, 205, 211, 62, 198, 219, 237, 221, 204, 209, 225, 218, 223, 227, 228, 219, 208, 209, 209, 222, 210, 56, 203, 196, 230, 202, 235, 209, 195, 229, 213, 223, 219, 225, 201, 211, 225, 188, 216, 223, 210, 207, 193, 222, 211, 211, 51, 231, 247, 217, 213, 176, 205, 215, 62, 208, 201, 63, 188, 188, 221, 206, 211, 196, 65, 236, 211, 175, 206, 219, 234, 221, 216, 197, 58, 213, 236, 233, 209, 208, 190, 210, 230, 216, 198, 226, 219, 220, 190, 223, 225, 213, 220, 219, 70, 185, 201, 67, 194, 197, 206, 46, 225, 202, 218, 197, 209, 245, 197, 227, 224, 197, 58, 225, 180, 229, 214, 186, 219, 50, 67, 232, 196, 210, 219, 194, 217, 210, 225, 225, 199, 208, 214, 224, 214, 223, 192, 216, 196, 191, 229, 215, 61, 218, 64, 223, 200, 59, 210, 233, 209, 213, 193, 55, 194, 230, 226, 225, 188, 68, 220, 197, 220, 204, 235, 42, 210, 205, 206, 221, 55, 59, 213, 208, 50, 59, 217, 218, 225, 56, 217, 216, 216, 223, 208, 203, 196, 192, 206, 195, 222, 201, 240, 52, 211, 190, 208, 220, 185, 227, 51, 43, 200, 237, 191, 227, 211, 185, 211, 216, 210, 218, 199, 56, 235, 218, 206, 209, 208, 42, 209, 210, 59, 216, 213, 55, 229, 229, 210, 225, 197, 54, 198, 75, 177, 185, 220, 211, 229, 201, 213, 201, 221, 208, 208, 179, 234, 232, 200, 220, 65, 201, 247, 210, 232, 213, 228, 211, 208, 221, 210, 203, 205, 179, 61, 236, 210, 190, 207, 201, 211, 210, 201, 196, 207, 232, 207, 214, 199, 219, 196, 63, 207, 192, 216, 197, 198, 232, 203, 200, 197, 196, 78, 206, 230, 205, 217, 207, 62, 221, 211, 193, 216, 64, 191, 66, 51, 223, 207, 197, 216, 60, 256, 206, 51, 239, 201, 60, 73, 50, 57, 55, 56, 221, 178, 76, 239, 200, 206, 58, 229, 68, 200, 231, 208, 57, 201, 63, 203, 227, 209, 211, 45, 200, 223, 60, 58, 60, 59, 198, 63, 60, 198, 188, 71, 214, 230, 205, 47, 223, 59, 55, 64, 63, 213, 61, 48, 228, 206, 209, 58, 64, 55, 195, 206, 214, 198, 210, 241, 65, 223, 56, 63, 241, 209, 197, 50, 224, 53, 59, 223, 68, 59, 70, 190, 234, 42, 220, 55, 67, 63, 209, 188, 221, 58, 64, 211, 56, 215, 237, 56, 53, 231, 66, 54, 52, 47, 57, 60, 49, 70, 65, 56, 199, 47, 60, 52, 54, 73, 47, 55, 58, 60, 56, 52, 62, 43, 49, 55, 62, 63, 57, 54, 56, 53, 57, 44, 39, 59, 50, 50, 69]
mean =  173.611
standard deviation =  68.194
number of latin squares =  576
number of low freq squares =  144
# IMPLMENTATION B
# SIMPLE CHANGE ELIMINATES THE ABOVE STRANGE LACK OF UNIFORMITY
# This version has a simple modification which removes the non-uniformity  
# demonstrated above and the result appears consistent with an 
# underlying uniform distribution.
# This is achieved by requiring each iteration to conclude with a proper square

import random
import time
import numpy as np

def rand2(a, b):
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return a, b
    return b, a

def Latin(n):
    xy = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    xz = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    yz = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            k = (i + j) % n
            xy[i][j] = k
            xz[i][k] = j
            yz[j][k] = i

    mxy, mxz, myz = 0, 0, 0
    m = [0, 0, 0]
    proper = True
    min_iter = n * n * n 
    for iter in range(min_iter):     # change code so that each iteration 
        itr = 0                      # concludes with a proper square
        while (itr<1 or not proper): # iterate until proper 
            itr = itr + 1
            if proper:
                i, j, k = random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1)
                while xy[i][j] == k:
                    i, j, k = random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1)
                i2 = yz[j][k]
                j2 = xz[i][k]
                k2 = xy[i][j]
                i2_, j2_, k2_ = i, j, k
            else:
                i, j, k = m
                i2, i2_ = rand2(yz[j][k], myz)
                j2, j2_ = rand2(xz[i][k], mxz)
                k2, k2_ = rand2(xy[i][j], mxy)

            proper = xy[i2][j2] == k2
            if not proper:
                m = [i2, j2, k2]
                mxy = xy[i2][j2]
                myz = yz[j2][k2]
                mxz = xz[i2][k2]

            xy[i][j] = k2_
            xy[i][j2] = k2
            xy[i2][j] = k2
            xy[i2][j2] = k

            yz[j][k] = i2_
            yz[j][k2] = i2
            yz[j2][k] = i2
            yz[j2][k2] = i

            xz[i][k] = j2_
            xz[i][k2] = j2
            xz[i2][k] = j2
            xz[i2][k2] = j

    
    return xy   # END OF TRANSLATED CODE

# CODE DEMONSTRATING ABOVE LEADS TO RESULT CONSISTENT WITH UNIFORM DISTRIBUTION
random.seed(time.time_ns())
N = 4
R = 100000

tabs = []
counts = []
ix = 0
for nm in range(R):
    t = Latin(N)
    try:
        ix = tabs.index(t)
    except ValueError:
        tabs.append(t)
        counts.append(1)
        
    ix = tabs.index(t)    
    counts[ix] = counts[ix] + 1
    
print( "list of frequency counts \n",counts)
print ("mean = ",round(np.mean(counts),3))
print( "standard deviation = ",round(np.std(counts),3))
print("number of latin squares = ",len(tabs))
    

Run of the above:
list of frequency counts
[160, 152, 200, 164, 180, 198, 170, 186, 172, 152, 190, 187, 168, 194, 188, 189, 180, 170, 185, 176, 173, 178, 172, 200, 181, 167, 162, 163, 171, 194, 168, 188, 191, 171, 170, 198, 163, 175, 189, 181, 165, 191, 154, 180, 162, 177, 166, 205, remainder removed due to character number limit mean =  174.611
standard deviation =  13.334
number of latin squares =  576
# IMPLEMENTATION C
 
# This version increases the number of iterations used in A but still
# exhibits non-uniformity.

import random
import time
import numpy as np

def rand2(a, b):
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return a, b
    return b, a

def Latin(n):
    xy = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    xz = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    yz = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            k = (i + j) % n
            xy[i][j] = k
            xz[i][k] = j
            yz[j][k] = i

    mxy, mxz, myz = 0, 0, 0
    m = [0, 0, 0]
    proper = True
    min_iter = n*n*n*n                    # increase min_iter by factor of n
    iter = 0                              # This code replaces a conditional Go 'for' statement
    while (iter<min_iter or not proper):  #
        iter = iter + 1                   # which did not translate correctly
        if proper:
            i, j, k = random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1)
            while xy[i][j] == k:
                i, j, k = random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1)
            i2 = yz[j][k]
            j2 = xz[i][k]
            k2 = xy[i][j]
            i2_, j2_, k2_ = i, j, k
        else:
            i, j, k = m
            i2, i2_ = rand2(yz[j][k], myz)
            j2, j2_ = rand2(xz[i][k], mxz)
            k2, k2_ = rand2(xy[i][j], mxy)

        proper = xy[i2][j2] == k2
        if not proper:
            m = [i2, j2, k2]
            mxy = xy[i2][j2]
            myz = yz[j2][k2]
            mxz = xz[i2][k2]

        xy[i][j] = k2_
        xy[i][j2] = k2
        xy[i2][j] = k2
        xy[i2][j2] = k

        yz[j][k] = i2_
        yz[j][k2] = i2
        yz[j2][k] = i2
        yz[j2][k2] = i

        xz[i][k] = j2_
        xz[i][k2] = j2
        xz[i2][k] = j2
        xz[i2][k2] = j

    return xy   # END OF TRANSLATED CODE

# CODE DEMONSTRATING NON UNIFORMITY FOR ORDER 4 LATIN SQUARES
# this code uses the above to generate R latin squares of order N and store a copy of 
# each distinct square in a list. (list very long if n > 4) 
# It tallies the number of occurences of each in a corresponding list.
# This aims to demonstrate that occurences occur in two distinct bands.
# for 100000 squares the count list indicates that frequencies of the latin
# squares are either less than 90 or greater than 170.
# 100 lies between these two bands and is used as a 'cut' to
# enable squares in the lower band to be placed in list lowtabs.
# Interestingly the number in the lower band is always 144, exactly a quarter of the 576
# latin squares of order 4. It is easily demonstrated that the same set of latin squares  
# constitutes the lower band for any execution of the program.

random.seed(time.time_ns())
N = 4        # order of latin squares
R = 100000   # number of repetitions 
tabs = []     # holds a copy of each distinct latin square
counts = []   # holds the corresponding frequency
cut =100
ix = 0

for nm in range(R):
    t = Latin(N)
    try:
        ix = tabs.index(t)  # test if already in list
    except ValueError:
        tabs.append(t)      # if not add to list
        counts.append(0)    # set count to zero
        
    ix = tabs.index(t)     
    counts[ix] = counts[ix] + 1  # increaase count
    


print( "list of frequency counts \n",counts)
print ("mean = ",round(np.mean(counts),3))
print( "standard deviation = ",round(np.std(counts),3))
print("number of latin squares = ",len(tabs))

lowcounts = []     # list of counts less than cut
lowtabs = []       # list of corresponding squares.
for k in range(len(counts)):
    if counts[k] < cut:
        lowtabs.append(tabs[k])
        lowcounts.append(counts[k])


print("number of low freq squares = ",len(lowtabs))


Run of the above:
list of frequency counts
[214, 233, 221, 188, 198, 188, 218, 225, 231, 189, 231, 219, 188, 228, 178, 217, 228, 196, 215, 231, 185, 201, 209, 204, 204, 231, 219, 188, 215, 217, 218, 220, 214, 192, 204, 222, 223, 232, 216, 207, 198, 229, 204, 231, 57, 197, 212, 228, 214, 50, 53, remainder removed
mean =  173.611
standard deviation =  68.324
number of latin squares =  576
number of low freq squares =  144
# IMPLEMENTATION D
# This version is similar to A but counts the 
# number of proper squares until a
# specified nunber is reached
# Interestingly this also restores uniformity

import random
import time
import numpy as np

def rand2(a, b):
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return a, b
    return b, a

def Latin(n):
    xy = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    xz = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    yz = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            k = (i + j) % n
            xy[i][j] = k
            xz[i][k] = j
            yz[j][k] = i

    mxy, mxz, myz = 0, 0, 0
    m = [0, 0, 0]
    proper = True
    countproper = 0   # initialse count of proper squares
    min_iter = n*n*n  # in this case this specifies the target number of proper squares 
                      # to be encountered on the walk
        
    while (countproper<min_iter or not proper):  # This code replaces previous by        
        if proper:                               # counting propers until min_iter is reached 
            countproper = countproper + 1
            i, j, k = random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1)
            while xy[i][j] == k:
                i, j, k = random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1), random.randint(0, n-1)
            i2 = yz[j][k]
            j2 = xz[i][k]
            k2 = xy[i][j]
            i2_, j2_, k2_ = i, j, k
        else:
            i, j, k = m
            i2, i2_ = rand2(yz[j][k], myz)
            j2, j2_ = rand2(xz[i][k], mxz)
            k2, k2_ = rand2(xy[i][j], mxy)

        proper = xy[i2][j2] == k2
        if not proper:
            m = [i2, j2, k2]
            mxy = xy[i2][j2]
            myz = yz[j2][k2]
            mxz = xz[i2][k2]

        xy[i][j] = k2_
        xy[i][j2] = k2
        xy[i2][j] = k2
        xy[i2][j2] = k

        yz[j][k] = i2_
        yz[j][k2] = i2
        yz[j2][k] = i2
        yz[j2][k2] = i

        xz[i][k] = j2_
        xz[i][k2] = j2
        xz[i2][k] = j2
        xz[i2][k2] = j
        
        
    return xy   # END OF TRANSLATED CODE

# CODE DEMONSTRATING UNIFORMITY OF ABOVE
# 

random.seed(time.time_ns())
N = 4        # order of latin squares
R = 100000   # number of repetitions 
tabs = []     # holds a copy of each distinct latin square
counts = []   # holds the corresponding frequency
cut =100
ix = 0

for nm in range(R):
    t = Latin(N)
    try:
        ix = tabs.index(t)  # test if already in list
    except ValueError:
        tabs.append(t)      # if not add to list
        counts.append(0)    # set count to zero
        
    ix = tabs.index(t)     
    counts[ix] = counts[ix] + 1  # increaase count
    


print( "list of frequency counts \n",counts)
print ("mean = ",round(np.mean(counts),3))
print( "standard deviation = ",round(np.std(counts),3))
print("number of latin squares = ",len(tabs))


Run of the above:
list of frequency counts
[203, 182, 194, 198, 182, 153, 158, 180, 181, 161, 172, 185, 168, 198, 178, 163, 192, 177, 157, 177, 179, 178, 165, 155, 169, 142, 192, 177, 159, 186, 201, 183, 177, 176, 195, 163, 174, 174, remainder removed
mean =  173.611
standard deviation =  13.207
number of latin squares =  576
# IMPLEMENTATION E
# Insert J-M Implementation A code here
# CODE TO REDUCE A LATIN SQUARE
def reduce(tab):
    dim = len(tab)
    b = np.full((dim,dim),0, dtype=int)
    c = np.full((dim,dim),0, dtype=int)
    d = np.full((dim,dim),0, dtype=int)
    e = np.full((dim,dim),0, dtype=int)
    for e in tab:
        b[e[0]]=e
    
    
    c=b.transpose()
    
    for e in c:
        d[e[0]]=e

    e=d.transpose()
    return e 

# code calling the above to obtain frequencies of order 5 
# reduced Latin squares

random.seed(time.time_ns())
N = 5         # order of latin squares
R = 200000    # number of squares to be generated 
tabs = []     # holds a copy of each distinct latin square
counts = []   # holds the corresponding frequency

ix = 0

for nm in range(R):
    u = Latin(N)   # get next random latin square
    v = reduce(u)  # reduce the square
    t = v.tolist() # format as list
    try:
        ix = tabs.index(t)  # test if already in list
    except ValueError:
        tabs.append(t)      # if not add to list
        counts.append(0)    # set count to zero
        
    ix = tabs.index(t)     
    counts[ix] = counts[ix] + 1  # increaase count
    

print("number of reduced latin squares = ",len(tabs))
print( "list of frequency counts \n",counts)
print( "sorted list of frequency counts \n")
# print( " list of corresponding reduced squares \n",tabs)
print(sorted(counts))

    

run of the above:
number of reduced latin squares =  56
list of frequency counts
[3519, 3436, 4694, 3439, 3408, 3478, 4553, 3465, 3398, 3381, 3409, 3395, 3505, 3467, 3583, 4588, 3347, 3408, 3457, 3559, 3357, 4420, 3382, 3438, 3442, 3443, 4575, 3382, 3405, 3498, 3479, 3466, 3388, 3631, 3455, 3499, 3462, 3386, 3365, 3329, 3588, 3359, 3607, 4525, 3508, 3443, 3392, 3458, 3548, 3493, 3386, 3473, 3474, 3539, 3536, 3380]
sorted list of frequency counts
[3329, 3347, 3357, 3359, 3365, 3380, 3381, 3382, 3382, 3386, 3386, 3388, 3392, 3395, 3398, 3405, 3408, 3408, 3409, 3436, 3438, 3439, 3442, 3443, 3443, 3455, 3457, 3458, 3462, 3465, 3466, 3467, 3473, 3474, 3478, 3479, 3493, 3498, 3499, 3505, 3508, 3519, 3536, 3539, 3548, 3559, 3583, 3588, 3607, 3631, 4420, 4525, 4553, 4575, 4588, 4694]
The last six counts in the sorted list are clearly significantly higher than the others.

The software has flagged your question as being "excessively long". Is it possible to host your code elsewhere and link to it? And the output (the long lists of frequency counts) aren't exactly needed for a human reader of the question, and should probably be also somewhere else.

To start with $n^3$ iterations is nowhere near enough. Multiply by 1000.  I don't understand all your comments, but for $n=4$ I get a correct coverage. There are two isotopy classes, one with isotopy group 32 and the other with isotopy group 96, so we expect 3/4 outputs in the first class and 1/4 in the second class. That's exactly what I get.

For $n=5$ there are again two isotopy classes, with group sizes 12 and 100. The ratio of outputs should be 100:12, which is precisely what I get.

The ratios you quoted apply when the underlying frequencies of individual squares are uniform. This is not the case in implementation A where, of the 100,000 order 4 squares generated, 8295 came from the smaller isotopy class while 91705 came from the larger. The ratio here is approx 1:11.  Quite a significant difference caused by the underlying frequency differences of individual latin squares. The primary question is: why does implementation A produce frequencies in the underlying latin squares which are not uniform while a seeming minor change (Implementation B) produces output which is?

I have run Implementation A with considerably higher iterations and obtained similar non uniform results and no observable trend toward uniformity as the number increases.
